# OpenStack-Swift clients?

Tags: client, openstack

Cloudberry Explorer for OpenStack storage is suitable client for OpenStack-Swift and it is found in the following link http://www.cloudberrylab.com/free-openstack-storage-explorer.aspx . I'm searching other clients which are exactly similar to this client. I did search in google, but I'm not quite sure about the ones that I found. Could you say the similar type of clients that are available as freeware? I'm doing some experiments, so I need several clients that are similar to Cloudberry Explorer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's Cyberduck. See http://trac.cyberduck.ch/wiki/help/en/howto/openstack for how to install and configure it.

Answer (score 3):

You can also look at the [associated Swift projects](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/associated_projects.html) for more options.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the tool [ExpandDrive](http://www.expandrive.com/) for browsing Cloud storage.

Also the explaination at [Swift Stack](http://swiftstack.com/openstack-swift/architecture/)  is useful to understand the Swift Object Storage.

Comment: Any chance you are affiliated with this product?

Comment: @AndrewBarber Am associated with OpenStack project not ExpandDrive.